# How do I make an Rx subject react to new elements added to the array?

Tags: ios, swift, observable, rx-swift

I would like my `subject` to `observe` changes on `myArray` so every time a new element is appended to `myArray` the `subscription` fires.

```
var subject = PublishSubject<[String]>()
var myArray = ["One", "Two"]

subject.flatMap{Observable.from($0)}.subscribe(onNext: {
    print($0)
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)

subject.onNext(myArray)

myArray.append("Three")

subject.onNext(myArray)
```

it works by adding `myArray` to `onNext` every time it changes, but is there a way for the `subscription` to trigger automatically when `myArray` gets a new `element` without using `onNext`? Perhaps by making `myArray` into an `observable`?

Comment: Make a wrapper struct, that conforms for `observable`, which wraps your array and provides an `append` method, which appends to the wrapped array but also triggers an `onNext` event. Most probably, somebody has already implemented such a thing, so I would search for that, first.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great time to take advantage of property wrappers. Be careful that you don't use this in a `struct` though.

```
@propertyWrapper
class RxPublished<Element> {
    private let subject: BehaviorSubject<Element>
    init(wrapped: Element) {
        subject = BehaviorSubject(value: wrapped)
    }

    deinit {
        subject.onCompleted()
    }

    var wrappedValue: Element {
        get { try! subject.value() }
        set { subject.onNext(newValue) }
    }

    var projectedValue: Observable<Element> {
        subject.asObservable()
    }
}


class MyClass {
    @RxPublished(wrapped: ["One", "Two"]) var myArray: [String]
}

func example() {
    let foo = MyClass()
    _ = foo.$myArray
        .debug("foo.myArray")
        .subscribe()

    foo.myArray.append("Three")
}
```